# exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

Is there any section in c++ for which we can not handle exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception of your own and handle it.
Are you trying to say places like constructors destructor in which case you can refer the following
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.2

Can you be more specific. What exactly are you looking for.

Comment: any pre/user defined function or variables for which we can not handle exception

Comment: @lalmay-j, what exactly do you mean by "can not handle exception"? Please add this clarification as an update to your original question, and remove this comment. SO is not working like a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

well the destructor must never throw and you must not use exception in signal handlers because that almost always doesn't end well if that's what your asking  but your question is a bit vague.

Comment: More like the destructor *shouldn't* throw, but it's perfectly fine to. I think the question isn't about should but about require.

Comment: Same thing about signal handlers - they should not exit by exception, but it _is_ acceptable to throw&catch in them.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one situation where an exception handler cannot handle an exception - a function try/catch block around a constructor.

The catch block(s) can translate the exception caught, but they cannot exit without throwing. See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm) for a more complete discussion.

---

*If you were asking about places from where exceptions cannot be thrown instead of where they cannot be handled then...*

Throwing an exception fro a destructor is extremely ill advised. The circumstances under which it is safe are so hard to guarantee that you should just avoid ever throwing from a destructor.